# What is the difference between those two ways?

Tags: c++

i just want to understand why i cant create object with braces like this ()
i dont understand what is the problem

"BSNode.h"

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class BSNode
{
public:
    BSNode() {
        
    }
    void printNodes() const {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

"main.cpp"

```
#include "BSNode.h"

int main()
{
    BSNode<int> bsnodeInt1();
    BSNode<int> bsnodeInt2;
    bsnodeInt1.printNodes();
    bsnodeInt2.printNodes();
    return 0;
}
```

im getting this two errors

> main.cpp 3 expression must have class type

> main.cpp 3 left of '.printNodes' must have class/struct/union

Comment: Because the first version is a function declaration, not a variable declaration.

Comment: This may help: [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BSNode<int> bsnodeInt1();` declares a function.

`BSNode<int> bsnodeInt2;` defines a new variable, it is initialized through the default constructor.

Comment: so cant i use braces to call an empty constructor?

Comment: Nope it's explicit you can do like this if you want. 
   A obj= A()

Comment: You can use `{}` instead of `()` from C++11 onwards.